# infix to postfix with white space

Tags: c, data-structures

I have a program which convert the infix form to postfix form.
example if the input is :`(-2+4-(3+3))`
then the output is : `2-4+33+-`
my expected ouput is : `2 - 4 + 3 3 + -`
How should I do to change it , I am thinking somethings like extra 1 more space when I pop() the stack.
Here is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include<string.h>

#define SIZE 50

char s[SIZE];
int top = -1;

void push(char elem) {
  s[++top] = elem;
}

char pop() {
  return (s[top--]);
}

int pr(char elem) {
  switch (elem) {
    case '#':
      return 0;
    case '(':
      return 1;
    case '+':
    case '-':
      return 2;
    case '*':
    case '/':
      return 3;
  }
}

int main()
{
  char infx[50], pofx[50], ch, elem;
  int i = 0, k = 0;
  printf("\n\nRead the Infix Expression ?");
  scanf("%s", infx);
  push('#');
  while ((ch = infx[i++]) != '\0') {
    if (ch=='(')
      push(ch);
    else if (isalnum(ch))
      pofx[k++] = ch;
    else if (ch == ')') {
      while (s[top] != '(')
        pofx[k++] = pop();
      elem = pop();
    } else {
      while (pr(s[top]) >= pr(ch))
        pofx[k++] = pop();
      push(ch);
    }
  }
  while (s[top] != '#')
    pofx[k++] = pop();
  pofx[k] = '\0';
  printf("\n\nGiven Infix Expn: %s Postfix Expn: %s \n", infx,pofx);
}
```

Thank you

Comment: You could try to write each element of postfix with a width of the size of the element + 1?

Comment: I am sorry, I dont get that.We dont know size of each element is

Comment: You can code a function int_width which gives you the size of an int, and you can print this int with intwidth + 1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well first off, I wasn't able to compile your code due to this line

```
int top = -1;

void push(char elem) {
s[++top] = elem;
}
```

It's very dangerous to initialize your arrays using a variable that's negative. When we go to `pop()` the character symbols in the array, it will return to its initial state at `top = -1` which causes the compilation error. My suggestion is to change your code around to something like this, which will lead you to change somethings around with placing characters in your array:

```
int top = 0;

void push(char elem) {
    s[top++] = elem;
}
```

As for printing your strings with spaces in between each character use something along the lines of:

```
for (int i = 0, i < stren(infix) + 1; i++)
{
    printf ("%c ", infix[i]);
}

// Same goes for the postfix. More of a formatting of the print characters really...
```

Comment: Yea, no problem - I would advise writing out some pseudo code before actually writing code it helps hash out mistakes that would otherwise be caught later.